# How to position form relative to an object in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to put a userform relative to a shape on sheet.
Form's `.top` and `.left` are relative to the top/left of screen while the same properties of shape are relative to top/left of cell A1.

How can I find A1 position relative to the top/left of screen to then position my form correctly? I have tried to measure the height of Ribbon with hope I will be able to do it but it does not work.

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.


    Dim ht As Integer = Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Height
    Dim lt As Integer = Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Left
    Top = Application.Top + ht
    Left = Application.Left + lt

End Sub
```

I hoped that the above code will give me the top/left corner of cell A1 but it does not. There are other issues like screen size/resolution as well as size of the Excel window.

Is there any "simple" method to calculate position of a form relative to the object in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the range of whatever is the top left cell. You could also use it to get the address, or the position.

```
Function getTopLeftVisibleCellAddress() As Range
   Set getTopLeftVisibleCellAddress = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Cells(1, 1)
End Function
```

you can then use this to get the row height and whatever else you need.

**More examples:**

*Verticle position:*

```
ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Cells(1, 1).top
```

*Horizontal*

```
ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Cells(1, 1).left
```

Combining it all, this macro will always reposition a shape to the same relative position on a worksheet. You can experiment with the constants at the top to get the exact location.

```
Sub fixYoShape()
Const hOffset As Long = 50 'use these to guide from your top left position
Const rOffset As Long = 20 'use these offsets to guide off your position
Const yourShapeName As String = "aShapeName" 'change this to be your shape name

Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim theRange As Range
    Set theRange = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Cells(1, 1)

With ws.Shapes(yourShapeName)
    .Top = theRange.Top + hOffset
    .Left = theRange.Left + rOffset
End With


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But even if I get the cell I have no way to define the position of this cell relative to the whole screen (to position my form correctly). Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, see updated answer, those top and left functions will get you an anchor point. You can then add whatever buffer pixel amount to have it display as you expect.

Comment: Thank you. Those Top and Left functions return 0 and when I try to position my form according to these values it sits in top left corner of the screen. I have tried that and it does not work as cell's top/left is relative to the cell area while form is relative to the window.

Comment: They don't always return zero... it depends where you are in your sheet. I'll update my answer with a sample to move a shape to a constant windo position, regardless of where the user is on the spreadsheet...

Comment: `.Top=Application.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)*72/96`
`.Left=Application.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)*72/96-5` where 96 is dpi of display works for me. 5 is like a constant.

Comment: In my above comment, it will still position correctly if you disable headings, formula bar etc. We are getting the pixels X and Y with respect to A1 left,top and hence 0. Depending on what you do, can get a bit complicated but A1 should be easy.